# How much time does it take for a free colonist to learn through experience?

Tags: colonization

In the manual, at page 34, it says

> Acquiring Skills: A free colonist that works at a particular job for
>   an extended period may become a specialist in that skill. The colonist
>   has learned through experience

How much time does it take for a `free colonist` to learn through experience?

Is it the same for all specialties or does it take more time for specialties taught in University rather than for specialties taught in school?

Comment: To clarify, is this the original 1994 game or the new remake?

Comment: @YiJiang'sEvilClone It's about the original one.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is random. You get a low chance each turn. I seem to recall more colonists becoming farmers than elder statesmen, but that could be memory and the fact that you just have more farmers for more turns.

Answer (score -1):

This may or may not be what you're looking for but there is a great section about Free colonists on his website ( [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.colonizationfans.com/education.html&ei=dN5nU4SYIc6lyATq8YGoCA&usg=AFQjCNErBmPM7-W4aITRUWB0CaBcdVCE1g&sig2=MUkxDRNfDGHQ1o5paM5TBQ) )

Comment: The link is great, thanks. But you should quote the interesting part just in case that the link becomes invalid.

Comment: @LucM I'm planning to, my work's firewall is blocking it because it deals with games. I'll include final information when i get home

Comment: The explanation [is still available on Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121010658/http://www.colonizationfans.com/education.html), but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @kubanczyk. Thank you for this link. It does not answer directly but it's mentionned:  `Finally, we have to consider how long it takes to teach a skill. It can take 4, 6 or 8 turns.`
It gives a good idea how long it takes.

Comment: That site's about teaching skills, not the (very rare) occurrence of a free colonist spontaneously learning a skill.

Comment: Can I assume that answerer still haven't made it to their home after 8 years?